# strip() removing extra (unwanted) character

Tags: python

In one of my projects I've been struck by the following scenario:

```py
word = 'mixed4d_pre_relu'
word.strip('_pre_relu')
Out[5]: 'mixed4d'
```

The output here is as expected.

However, when I do the following:

```py
word = 'mixed4e_pre_relu'
word.strip('_pre_relu')
Out[5]: 'mixed4'  # No 'e' here, yyy?
```

Does anyone have an idea of what would be the cause of such behavior?

Comment: strip is not removing a fixed series of chars. It takes a list of chars to be removed regardless of position. It doesnt remove a prefix etc

Comment: Shouldn't it remove other 'e' in the word, too?

Comment: it only removes from the start or end. I.E take any chars in your list and keep removing them from the start and end until you reach a char thats not in the list

Comment: Of course it does not. Please read the [official documentation on `str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) before asking further questions. Specifically: "... The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, **all combinations of its values** are stripped" and ".. The **outermost leading and trailing chars** argument values are stripped from the string."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the comments, `.strip()` takes a list of characters and strips all of them - not a string to strip in particular. It will do so at the ends of the string, moving inwards until it finds something not part of that character set, at which point it will stop.

An alternative that will do what you want (at least in this case) is regex replacement:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'_pre_relu$', '', word)
'mixed4d'
```

This simply looks for the text `_pre_relu` at the very end of the string, thus serving as a `rstrip()`. The equivalent `lstrip()` replacement would be `r'^_pre_relu'`, which would remove that text at the very beginning of the string, instead.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies the thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not strange. It's as per the given functionality of str.strip('chars').
Even `word.rstrip('luerp_')` will give the same result as it tries to remove all the chars provided as argument from the `word` till it finds a mismatch which is `4` in your case.