# How to use strip method correctly?

Tags: python

I've a string `'XCeed Plug-in Hybride'` and I'm trying to get `'XCeed'`.

Using `strip` method:

```
>>> 'XCeed Plug-in Hybride'.strip(' Plug-in Hybride')
'XC'
```

I even tried using `rstrip`, still getting same output.

```
>>> 'XCeed Plug-in Hybride'.rstrip(' Plug-in Hybride')
'XC'
```

Although I could use other methods like list or other ways, but I would love get required output from `strip` method. So can anyone suggest where I'm getting wrong or what I need to do make it working.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60395380/3001761

Answer (score 0):

I think you want *split* here, rather than strip:

```py
inp = "XCeed Plug-in Hybride"
output = inp.split()[0]
print(output)  # XCeed
```

This splits the input by (default) space, and then retains just the first item.

An alternative using regex:

```py
inp = "XCeed Plug-in Hybride"
output = re.sub(r' .*', '', inp)
print(output)  # XCeed
```

This strips off the first space until the end of the string, leaving behind the first term.